# Short exact sequence with p-adic integers and $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am working through Gouvêa's *p-adic Numbers: An Introduction*, and Problem 94 is to verify that the following forms a short exact sequence 
$$
0\to\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\to0
$$
where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the p-adic integers, $\mathbb{Z}_p=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}_p:|x|\leq 1\}$, and the first map is given by multiplication by $p^n$. I understand why $0\to\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Z}_p$ is exact, as it is multiplication in a field. What I am unsure of is what the map $\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is.

In the hint, Gouvêa states that this map comes out of the proof of Proposition 3.3.3; unfortunately, there is no such proposition. My only idea is that I *think* I can write $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a disjoint union
$$
\mathbb{Z}_p=\cup_{k=0}^{p^n-1}B\left(k,\frac{1}{p^n}\right),
$$
with $B\left(k,\frac{1}{p^n}\right)$ the open ball of radius $\frac{1}{p^n}$ around $k$,
so then I can map $\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ in the obvious way.

Is this the correct map? If it is, is there a better way of thinking about this? It seems like a pretty roundabout way of defining this, and I don't want to move on in the book without being sure of what the map should be. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term on the RHS is in fact $\mathbb{Z}_p/ p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$. Now you have to show that we also have an isomorphism 
$$\mathbb{Z}/ p^n \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_p/ p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$$ coming from the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}_p$. The injectivity is easy, the surjectivity  comes from the fact that 
$$\mathbb{Z} + p^n \mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Z}_p$$ ( not direct). This is equivalent to: for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ there exists $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $d(a,z) \le \frac{1}{p^n}$. 
(This statement, for all $n$, is equivalent to the density of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$)

Comment: In the book the term on the RHS is $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, and in fact they use this to conclude $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}_p/p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$. I am looking for the direct map to $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The direct map is $\sum_{m\ge 0} a_m p^m \mapsto \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} a_m p^m$, if you consider the canonical writing, and the smallest representative in the ring of residues.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit map I think is from the previous proposition as the author mentioned. In my edition (Second edition), Proposition 3.3.4 says the following:

Given $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $n \geq 1$, there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq \alpha \leq p^n-1$ such that $|x-\alpha|\leq p^{-n}$. The integer $\alpha$ with these properties is unique.

This is the density mentioned by another user with an extra condition on the integer.

Consider the map $x \mapsto [\alpha]$ where $[\alpha]$ is the equivalence class of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$

If $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\alpha, \beta$ are the corresponding integers mentioned in the Proposition. To show that the above map is indeed a homomorphism, first see that

If $\alpha \equiv \beta ~(\bmod{~p^n}~)$ and $|x-\alpha| \leq p^{-n}$, then

$$ |x-\beta| = |x-\alpha+p^nm| \leq \max(|x-\alpha|, |p^nm|) \leq p^{-n} $$

Here we used that $|p^nm| = |p^n||m| \leq |p^n| = p^{-n}$.

$$ |x+y -(\alpha+\beta)| \leq \max (|x-\alpha|,|y-\beta|) \leq p^{-n} $$

Hence if we choose $\gamma \equiv \alpha+\beta~(\bmod{~p^n}~)$ with the property that $0 \leq \gamma \leq p^n-1$, we obtain

$$ |x+y-\gamma| \leq p^{-n} $$

By uniqueness, we get $[\alpha] + [\beta] = [\gamma]$.

Multiplication works in a similar way. Surjectivity is clear as $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}_p$.