# To prove $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ is isomorphic to $\lim_{←}\Bbb{Z}_p/p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ as a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory, limits-colimits

I want to prove $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ is isomorphic to $\lim_{←}\Bbb{Z}_p/p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ as a ring.
Here, $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is completion (as metric space) of
$\Bbb{Z}$ with p adic metric.

My try:

Let define natural ring hom $ \Bbb{Z}_p→\lim_{←}\Bbb{Z}_p$ by $a→(\cdots,a \pmod {p^2},a \pmod p)$.
This is clearly injective since Ker is $0$ (note that $ \bigcap {p^n\Bbb{Z}_p}＝0$).

But how can I prove **surjectivity** ?
I guess I use **completeness of $\Bbb{Z}_p$**(every caushy sequence converges), but I don't have confident.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's your definition of $\mathbb Z_p$? Can you please add it?

Comment: Often the definition is the inverse limit $\displaystyle{\mathbb{Z}_p=\varprojlim\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}}$. Now we have $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z_p/p^n\Bbb Z_p$ and we are done.

Comment: And the latter is proved in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439864/short-exact-sequence-with-p-adic-integers-and-mathbbz-pn-mathbbz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the answer depends on the definitions, and in your case, the completeness is indeed the key.

Given any $(a_1+p\mathbb Z, a_2+p^2\mathbb Z, \cdots)\in \lim \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$, we show that $\{a_n\}\in\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Z_p$ is a Cauchy sequence. Due to compatibility, we know that $a_n\equiv a_m \mod p^{m}$ for all $n\ge m$, hence $|a_n-a_m|_p\le p^{-m}$ which is small for sufficiently large $m$.

Let $a=\lim a_n$, we have the image of $a$ is $(a_i+p^i\mathbb Z)$. Indeed, let $n\rightarrow\infty$ in $|a_n-a_m|_p\le p^{-m}$ we have $|a-a_m|_p\le p^{-m}$, i.e. $a\equiv a_m \mod p^m$.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, it is very helpful. I'm wondering the converse holds. If the isom holds, then can we say $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ is complete as metric space ?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472423/bbb-z-p-cong-lim-

Comment: I want to hear your opinion and answer. Thank you for your help.