# $\Bbb {Z}_p \cong lim_{←n} \Bbb{Z}_p/p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$(set theoretic bijection) implies $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ is complete as metric space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

$\Bbb {Z}_p \cong lim_{←n} \Bbb{Z}_p/p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$,$a→(・・・,amodp^2,amodp$),(set theoretic bijection) implies $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ is complete as metric space ?

Completeness of ring is often defined as completion as ring $lim_{←n} \Bbb{Z}_p/p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ is isom(as ring)to $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ itself.
I want to know relation between the definition of completeness using cushy sequence.
Titled question is what I want to know. 'Yes or No' answer and just hint is also appreciated (ofcourse selecontained answer is really welcomed).
Thank you for your help.

Comment: A mere set-theoretic bijection between metric spaces does not imply they are complete.  For example, $\mathbf R$, $\mathbf R - \{0\}$ and $\mathbf R - \{0,1\}$ have the same cardinality, so there is a set-theoretic bijection between any two of them, but as metric spaces in the usual way the first one is complete and the second and third are not.

Comment: Sorry, my notation was ambiguous, set theoretic bijection in this case is for concrete mapping, we are saying more strong thing than there exists bijection.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less true, but set theoretical bijection isn't the key. There is [an algebraic completion](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00M9), which makes the projective limit $\lim \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ a completion. It coincides with the metric completion in this case.

To be a little bit more precise, consider a (unital commutative) ring $R$ with an ideal $I$. We can define a (pseudo)metric on $R$ by $d(a,b) = r^{\max \{n | a-b\in I^n\}}$. (When $\cap_n I^n=\{0\}$, this is a metric, otherwise we get a metric on the quotient ring.) It can be shown that the uniform structure induced by the metric doesn't depend on the choice of $0<r<1$ (in the $p$-adic case, $r=\frac{1}{p}$ to make the product formula hold). Therefore the completion doesn't depend on the choice of $r$ either.

Now we can complete $R$ with respect to the metric $d$. This turns out to be isomorphic to the algebraic completion $\lim R/I^n$, and the proof is more or less straightforward.

More generally, we could have valuations on a ring which are not necessarily rank 1 (hence cannot be defined by a metric), but we still can make completions along them. This is quite useful in the theory of adic and perfectoid spaces. See e.g. [Brian Conrad's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/Adicnotes.pdf).

Comment: 'A ring $R$ is complete with respect to an ideal $I$ if the natural map $R\rightarrow\varprojlim_{n\geq 1}R/I^n$ is an isomorphism. This is the same as asking that $R$ is complete (in the sense that every Cauchy sequence converges) with respect to the $I$-adic topology. '  In such a statement,  'isomrphism' is set theoretic bijection  ?  Or topological isomorphism ? I want to clarify that.

Comment: It's a ring isomorphism. Topology is encoded in the algebraic structure.